# Add converted svg obj to Raphael canvas

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm building a web app which contains layers. I have a lot of images and that's why I decided to use SVG. I found [this site](http://toki-woki.net/p/SVG2RaphaelJS/) that create a Raphael Obj. After I create the object I add it to my paper:

```
var treesLayer=[0,0,3492,768, 
{"type":"path","stroke":"none","path":"M680.647,191.686c18.363-24.107,13.71-5...
```

Only part of the object because it's too long.

```
//Adding the object to the paper 
TreesStrip = Raphael(treesLayer);
```

I know the the function Raphael creates new canvas paper and draw the element over there. 
I think that's the reason that my D&D is ruined. I didn't find any better way to add the new element to the paper. If any one know how to add a converted SVG element into Raphael paper. I'll appreciate your help. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit rusty, but I think you might be off a bit; parameter to Raphael(something) should actually reflect a div.

`<div id="my_paper" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>`

With this div, you initialize RaphaelJS:

`var paper = Raphael( "my_paper" );`

Once that's setup, we'll assume your treesLayer variable exists:

`var trees = paper.path( treesLayer.path );`

It's probable that your path is natively 1000-ish pixels wide, so, resize accordingly.

Comment: I tried that, the problem is that the json which represent Raphael obj contains couple of paths...

Comment: It's up to you to either combine path strings, or, insert multiple objects (var trees = new Array(); trees.push( paper.path( .. ) ).  Nature of SVG documents and their exports can't be predicted; your path string above didn't mention that fragmentation.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but I've got an array of objects.
I wanted to have just one Raphael object.
I'll be clear, I want to import a SVG image into Raphael Canvas.
I already made a process with the way of thinking you gave me before: I succeeded to render the Json object that I created, but I can't use this as a Raphael object.